# json_encode/json_decode - returns stdClass instead of Array in PHP

Tags: php, json

Observe this little script:

```
$array = array('stuff' => 'things');
print_r($array);
//prints - Array ( [stuff] => things )
$arrayEncoded = json_encode($array);
echo $arrayEncoded . "<br />";
//prints - {"stuff":"things"}
$arrayDecoded = json_decode($arrayEncoded);
print_r($arrayDecoded);
//prints - stdClass Object ( [stuff] => things )
```

Why does PHP turn the JSON Object into a class?

Shouldn't an array that is `json_encoded` then `json_decoded` yield the EXACT same result?

Answer (score 98):

```
$arrayDecoded = json_decode($arrayEncoded, true);
```

gives you an array.

Comment: This is so woefully helpful, thank you @Kai Chain - I suppose the original question was asking, "Why", but this seems to get at what they intended.  Whatever the case, perfect for my situation.

Comment: And does the same job after 4 years here! Basic knowledge that everyone should actually study first, like me!

Answer (score 30):

#### To answer the actual question:

> ***Why does PHP turn the JSON Object into a class?***

Take a closer look at the output of the encoded JSON, I've extended the example the OP is giving a little bit:

```
$array = array(
    'stuff' => 'things',
    'things' => array(
        'controller', 'playing card', 'newspaper', 'sand paper', 'monitor', 'tree'
    )
);
$arrayEncoded = json_encode($array);
echo $arrayEncoded;
//prints - {"stuff":"things","things":["controller","playing card","newspaper","sand paper","monitor","tree"]}
```

The JSON format was derived from the same standard as JavaScript (*ECMAScript Programming Language Standard*) and if you would look at the format it looks like JavaScript. It is a JSON **object** (**`{}` = object**) having a property "stuff" with value "things" and has a property "things" with it's value being an array of strings (**`[]` = array**).

**JSON (as JavaScript) doesn't know associative arrays only indexed arrays.** So when JSON encoding a PHP associative array, this will result in a JSON string containing this array as an "object".

Now we're decoding the JSON again using `json_decode($arrayEncoded)`. The decode function doesn't know where this JSON string originated from (a PHP array) so it is decoding into an unknown object, which is `stdClass` in PHP. As you will see, the "things" array of strings WILL decode into an indexed PHP array.

Also see:

- [RFC 4627 - The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627.html)
- [RFC 7159 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchang](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html)
- [PHP Manual - Arrays](http://docs.php.net/types.array)

---

<sup>Thanks to https://www.randomlists.com/things for the 'things'</sup>

Comment: this is the correct answer... it answers the question, whereas the other ones give workarounds to an unexplained problem. Thanks, I was going in circles forgetting that JSON didn't support associative arrays!

Answer (score 7):

Although, as mentioned, you could add a second parameter here to indicate you want an array returned:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Many people might prefer to cast the results instead:

```
$array = (array)json_decode($json);
```

It might be more clear to read.

Comment: There are different. Be aware if you have encoded a multidimensional array or object. First one gives you array of arrays, second one gives you array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: JavaScript doesn't support associative arrays, therefore neither does JSON.

After all, it's JSON, not JSAAN. :)

So PHP has to convert your array into an object in order to encode into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var_dump(json_decode('{"0":0}'));    // output: object(0=>0)
    var_dump(json_decode('[0]'));          //output: [0]

    var_dump(json_decode('{"0":0}', true));//output: [0]
    var_dump(json_decode('[0]', true));    //output: [0]
```

If you decode the json into array, information will be lost in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good PHP 4 json encode / decode library (that is even PHP 5 reverse compatible) written about in this blog post: [Using json_encode() and json_decode() in PHP4 (Jun 2009)](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/).

The concrete code is by Michal Migurski and by Matt Knapp:

- [JSON-PHP / january 2005](http://mike.teczno.com/json.html)
- Code: http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps
- Pear Proposal: http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198
- Pear Package: http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON