# json encode return as objects instead array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281973/json-encode-json-decode-returns-stdclass-instead-of-array-in-php) and doesn't answer my issue.

I have an Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COM] => 10659.68
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MCD] => 1219.09
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MCR] => 77047.65
        )

)
```

And when I make a json_encode() it return this;

```
[{"COM":10659.68},{"MCD":1219.09},{"MCR":77047.65}]
```

What I need is get the data in this way:

```
[["COM":10659.68],["MCD":1219.09],["MCR":77047.65]]
```

Any idea how can I achieve this

Comment: The first is valid JSON, second is not.

Comment: You can't expect json_encode() to return an invalid JSON

Comment: if you are sure about the format of the content of each string I think you could make a regex replace on the json_encode output, did you try?

Comment: @lelloman I'm going to try..thnks for the idea

Comment: yw, @RubenSerratePardo gave the answer maybe you don't need to write it ;)

Comment: @lelloman I'will accept in 5 min...the system doesn't let me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though that's not a valid JSON, you can replace the { with [

```
echo str_replace(array('{','}'),array('[',']'),json_encode($your_array));
```

Depending on the content you might need a more complex replacement with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

More complex solution:

```
function toJson($arr){
    $return = array();
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)) $return[] = toJson($v);
        else $return[] = sprintf('"%s":%s', $k, $v);
    }
    return sprintf('[%s]', implode(',', $return));
}
```

Test:

```
$input = array(
    array('COM' => '10659.68'),
    array('MCD' => '1219.09'),
    array('MCR' => '77047.65'), 
);
var_dump(toJson($input));
```

> string(51) "[["COM":10659.68],["MCD":1219.09],["MCR":77047.65]]"