# Fetching json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have problem with fetching json array that i send with `post` by android app.
`PHP` code :

```
<?php
$properties_json = json_decode($_POST['property'], true);
foreach ($properties_json->properties as $pro_element) {
   echo $pro_element->property_id . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element->property_name . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element->property_value . '---------';
}
```

`JSON` array that i post :

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "property_id": "654",
      "property_name": "Gender",
      "property_value": "Male"
    },
    {
      "property_id": "655",
      "property_name": "Name",
      "property_value": "Amin"
    },
    {
      "property_id": "656",
      "property_name": "Mobile",
      "property_value": "654-451-456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error :

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t0l1.png)

Comment: can you use print_r($properties_json->properties)? what is output?

Comment: You set true in json_decode, so it's array. not object - `$properties_json['properties']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode/json\_decode - returns stdClass instead of Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281973/json-encode-json-decode-returns-stdclass-instead-of-array-in-php)

Comment: @splash58 There is no difference

Comment: @Shujaat Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Please make sure that `$_POST['property']` contains a valid `JSON` string, otherwise `json_decode` will result in `NULL`

Comment: Check content of `$properties_json` by `var_dump()`

Comment: @Mohammad it includes the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_decode($_POST['property'], true);` return an array. In your code you're using it as an object. Here is the proper way :

```
<?php
$properties_json = json_decode($_POST['property'], true);

foreach ($properties_json['properties'] as $pro_element) {
   echo $pro_element['property_id'] . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element['property_name'] . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element['property_value'] . '---------';
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can check if `$_POST['property']` exist and is not null.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['property'])){
    if($_POST['property'] != null and $_POST['property'] != ""){
        $properties_json = json_decode($_POST['property'], true);

        foreach ($properties_json['properties'] as $pro_element) {
            echo $pro_element['property_id'] . '<br/>';
            echo $pro_element['property_name'] . '<br/>';
            echo $pro_element['property_value'] . '---------';
        }
    }else{
        echo "POST['property'] is empty";
    }
}else{
    echo "Missing POST['property']";
}
```

Comment: You should also check that `$properties_json` is not `NULL` though

Answer (score 1):

You reference `$properties_json->properties` as if it were an object, but you converted your JSON to an array by doing `json_decode($_POST['property'], true);` (see the [documentation of json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

You either need to change the `true` to false or do 
`foreach ($properties_json['properties'] as $pro_element) {`

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you sure you do actually POST anything and that $_POST['property'] contains a JSON array?

Comment: If I execute this

<?php
$_POST['property'] = '{
  "properties": [
    {
      "property_id": "654",
      "property_name": "Gender",
      "property_value": "Male"
    }
  ]
}';
$properties_json = json_decode($_POST['property'], false);
foreach ($properties_json->properties as $pro_element) {
   echo $pro_element->property_id . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element->property_name . '<br/>';
   echo $pro_element->property_value . '---------';
}

I get the expected result: 654<br/>Gender<br/>Male---------